# custom wpf control used in listbox with binding

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

Im new to WPF. I try to bind to the click event on the listBox element. Element is TextBlock so it doesnt work as expected so that I decided to create custom control:

ClickableTextBlock:

xaml:

```
<Button VerticalAlignment="Center"  Name="btnButton" HorizontalAlignment="Center" >
    <Button.Template>
        <ControlTemplate>
            <TextBlock Name="tbText"></TextBlock>    
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Button.Template>
</Button>
```

What I would like to achive is to be able to control from the main xaml code where is the listBox, what property of the dataContext to bind to the custom control and what command bind to thje click event of this custom control:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Items.Result}" Margin="0,5,0,10" x:Name="listBox" >
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="0" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                    <!-- my custom control here:  -->
                    <controls:ClickableTextBlock ... <HERE PUT THE CODE...> >
                    </controls:ClickableTextBlock>
                </StackPanel>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

what is the best aproach if possible to do sth like that ?

Comment: you should expose the `Button` `Command` so you could write some thing like `<controls:ClickableTextBlock Command ="{Binding YourCommand}"/>`

Comment: and what about binding the text to the bound property ?

Comment: you should basically expose all the stuff you may need like: Width,Height,Text, Click, Command, Border, Background, TextColor, Margin, Padding, ...

Comment: also **if** your ClickableTextBlock is just the xaml with no codebehind this customcontrol makes no sense in my oppinion, just throw it in your StackPanel and wire the Bindings